# how to stringify json in flutter

Tags: json, dart, flutter

In flutter(dart), it is easy to deserialize `Json` and get a token from it, but when I try to serialize it again, the quotation marks around the keys and values with disappear.

```
String myJSON = '{"name":{"first":"foo","last":"bar"}, "age":31, "city":"New York"}';
var json = JSON.jsonDecode(myJSON); //_InternalLinkedHashMap
var nameJson = json['name']; //_InternalLinkedHashMap
String nameString = nameJson.toString();
```

Although the `nameJson` have all the double quotations, the `nameString` is

`{first: foo, last: bar}`

*(true answer is `{"first": "foo", "last": "bar"}`)*

how to preserve Dart to remove the `"`s?

Comment: I want a `json string` that can use again for `JsonDecoder`, when the quotation marks remove, the string is not a valid `json` no longer

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When encoding the object back into JSON, you're using .toString(), which does *not* convert an object to valid JSON. Using jsonEncode fixes the issue.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String myJSON = '{"name":{"first":"foo","last":"bar"}, "age":31, "city":"New York"}';
  var json = jsonDecode(myJSON);
  var nameJson = json['name'];
  String nameString = jsonEncode(nameJson); // jsonEncode != .toString()
  print(nameString); // outputs {"first":"foo","last":"bar"}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a map, and you want to stringify it into a string variable, then all what you need to do is:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = {...};
String stringifiedString = jsonEncode(map);
```

The output will be:

```
"{\"name\":{\"first\":\"foo\",\"last\":\"bar\"}, \"age\":31, \"city\":\"New York\"}"
```

You can read more about this on the [documentation page](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#:%7E:text=To%20encode%20a%20user%2C%20pass,already%20does%20it%20for%20you.&text=String%20json%20%3D%20jsonEncode(user)%3B,about%20JSON%20serialization%20at%20all.).