# Convert double Quotes array "[]" to Pure Array object Node JS, BodyParser

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, multer, body-parser

so here is the problem :
I am passing a list/array of objects from front end to my node js back end.

This is how it looks on the front end : [{"sample1": "this", "apple2" : eat},{"sample2": "thisIs2", "apple3" : eatFruits}]

but when it is passed to the backend , its converted to String,something like this:
"[{"sample1": "this", "apple2" : eat},{"sample2": "thisIs2", "apple3" : eatFruits}]"

So when I run a for loop in my node js, the length is calculated as each characters. what do i do to get the pure array and the contents in the array. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string to JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976897/converting-a-string-to-json-object)

Comment: Use `JSON.parse("[{"sample1": "...)`

Comment: @ask4you Anytime I use that, it throws this error .. SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 2

Comment: @lusc It didn't help. I tried already, I used JSON.parse, it throws this error ... SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 2

Comment: Sounds like you're incorrectly stringifying it then. You'll need to debug how it's being sent. The string you've posted is indeed invalid due to missing quotes around the object values `eat` and `eatFruits`, but that  could  easily  be a typo  on  your  part

Comment: @pilchard here is what I'm doing..     var q = JSON.parse(req.body.toppings)
            console.log(typeof(req.body.toppings))---> the type shows String

Comment: but what about on the front end? How are you  encoding  it before  sending.

Comment: @pilchard here is how it is sent from flutter...    ``var newObject = {
        "topping": "${selectedItems[i].toppings['topping']}",
        "price": "${selectedItems[i].toppings['price']}",
        "quantity": "${selectedItems[i].quantity}"
      };

      newMapToppingsAsList.add(newObject);
      print(newObject);``

Comment: @pilchard i'm sending it as A multipart request in flutter. Is that right?

Comment: You need to appropriately stringify it see: [how to stringify json in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487659/how-to-stringify-json-in-flutter)

Comment: @that_flutter_guy Yea, i think because `eat` and `eatFruit` are functions/classes which can't be parsed  or stringified with `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

`"[{"sample1": "this", "apple2" : eat},{"sample2": "thisIs2", "apple3" : eatFruits}]"`
Your object is the **"stringified"** JSON. Means whole JSON object represented as string

e.g.

```js
const jsonObj = [{"id": 1, "name": "John"}, {"id": 2, name: "Jane"}];
const strigified = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
console.log(strigified);
```

output

```js
'[{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"Jane"}]'
```

This can be reversed by parsing this string as JSON

```js
const original = JSON.parse(strigified);
console.log(original);
```

output

```js
[{"id": 1, "name": "John"}, {"id": 2, name: "Jane"}]
```

`JSON.strigify()` & `JSON.parse()` are exactly reciprocal methods...